# How can I encode from unicode to GB18030 in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode

I know how to do this in `Python`:

```
In [1]: u'中华人民共和国'.encode('GB18030').encode('base64')
Out[1]: '1tC7qsjLw/G5srrNufo=\n'
```

But I need to do this in PHP, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Note that Unicode is *not* a (binary) character encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the string from UTF-8 (or whatever your initial encoding is) to GB18030, then [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) the result. E.g.:

```
echo base64_encode(iconv('UTF-8', 'GB18030', '中华人民共和国'));
```

outputs:

```
1tC7qsjLw/G5srrNufo=
```

---

Note that PHP doesn't have native Unicode strings - they're just a bunch of bytes, so you'll need to specify the encoding the string is in. If it's a string literal in your PHP it'll be whatever encoding you've used for the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "gb18030", "UTF-8");
```

replace UTF-8 with whatever encoding the text is in already. Or the third parameter is optional, it might work even without that.

[mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)